# Nginx rewrite with basic regex

Tags: nginx

Trying to get
http://example.com/shop/donate?id=123
to redirect to 
http://example.com/donate/123

With the below in my .conf, hitting the top URL does not result in a redirect. Other redirects in the .conf are working. Any thoughts?

```
server{
  ....
  rewrite ^/shop/donate?id=([0-9]+)$ /donate/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want this? Probably your application would better place for that redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use $arg_[name] for this case:

```
rewrite ^/shop/donate$ /donate/$arg_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the question mark, else it gets parsed as regex:

```
server{
  ....
  rewrite ^/shop/donate\?id=([0-9]+)$ /donate/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: I've added that, still not redirecting